# Meaning of InvalidToken - No exception message supplied using python cryptography

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on a project using this package from github with version 1.2.3

https://github.com/pyca/cryptography

i keep getting an error like this

```
InvalidToken at /admin/documentsearch/add/
No exception message supplied
```

not sure what this means though unfortunataley and i'm not sure how to proceed. Has anybody encountered this before? This particular issue doesn't seem to be in the github repo's issue list as well. Hoping somebody could assist me with this particular issue

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized what it was eventually. The django SECRET_KEY of the database i was copying from is different from the SECRET_KEY in my local settings. I used the SECRET_KEY in the settings of the setup i was copying from to match the one used in its DB and its working now

thanks